# How to publish a project with extern Data correctly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, publish

I'm trying to publish a project which needs some data which is stored in a .txt file.

The file is currently located in bin\Debug.
The Path for the Streamreader is relative using Applicaton.StartupPath.
I added the .txt file to the solution explorer, but somehow i get a bad path error message every time i try to start the published setup.

How do I publish my Project with the needed .txt File?

Answer (score 0):

You have various ways of achieving this.

1. The txt file included in the solution file will have a property called Build Action. Change it to Content and it should be published with your deployments.
2. You can add it to your resources, but then you will need to access it differently.
3. Add it to your installation package

Comment: Ok, I Changed it to Content, but i still get the error message.  My full Path is Application.StartupPath+@"\Build\Instruct\SLInstruct.txt", is there anything wrong with that?

Comment: Can you see the txt file in your published folder?

Comment: in my publish folder there is my setup a click once and another folder named Application Files. This Folder contains a folder for each publish of my project i have done so far, the newest of these folders contains the bin folder which contains the Folders Debug\Build\SLInstruct. and then there is my textfile saved as SLInstruct.txt.deploy

Comment: Now when you install the application, do you see a txt file in the path where the exe is deployed.

Comment: I followed the path to AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\... but at the path in the error message is missing the folders bin and Debug. I can find these folders by myself and the textfiles are there. But the error path skips the two folders, so it cant find the text files. But why does it do so and how can i fix this ?

Comment: What is the full path of your txt file once deployed and what is the full path you are trying to access through code?

Comment: The Programm tries to get the file through C:\Users\mschroer\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\3987ERG6.TDD\Y7HX7WDO.54H\gpmf..tion_b5c6c07d3b38b61f_0000.0001_95f7e24abef4c65d\Build\Instruct\SLInstruct.txt.   But the deployed text-file is here C:\Users\mschroer\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\3987ERG6.TDD\Y7HX7WDO.54H\gpmf..tion_b5c6c07d3b38b61f_0000.0001_95f7e24abef4c65d\bin\Debug\Build\Instruct\SLInstruct.txt